# Disable Glimpse in a Modal iFrame

Tags: jquery, .net, iframe, glimpse

I am attempting to use the Nuget Package Glimpse for details on my website.  We use JQuery Modals throughout the site that load an iframe inside the Modal.  Glimpse launches inside the iframe, but covers too much real estate in the modal to be useful.

Is there a configuration to disable Glimpse if it is inside an iframe?

I tried adding it as a content Type in the web.config but that was not successful.

```
<glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd" >
  <runtimePolicies>
    <contentTypes>
      <add contentType="iframe" runtimePolicy="Off"/>
    </contentTypes>
  </runtimePolicies>
</glimpse>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable Glimpse for any given URL using the URI's section of the `runtimePolicies` element. Simply add the URL that the iFrame(s) are pointing to.

Take a look at the **URIs** section of the [configuration documentation](http://getglimpse.com/Help/Configuration) for an example.